# Variable Sized Object May not be initialized, error

Tags: c

What I am to do with this code is encrypt a char array by shifting each letter by a set amount of characters (if amount is 2 then characters are shifted twice - e.g. 'a' -> 'c').

I am getting the following error and warning.

```
Error on line 39: Variable Sized Object May not be initialized.
Warning on line 39 : Unused Variable cyph
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int CharToAlphaNumber (char letter)
{
    int alpha;
    int ascii=letter;
    if (ascii >= 65 && ascii <=90)
    {
        alpha= ascii - 64;
    }
    else if (ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122)
    {
        alpha= ascii - 96;
    }
    return alpha;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        puts ("You need to enter a key, only one argument");
    }
    else
    {
        int key = atoi(argv[1]);
        puts ("Give me text:");
        char plaintext[100];
        scanf ("%s", plaintext);
        printf ("You entered %s\n",plaintext);

        char cyph[100];
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<strlen(plaintext);i++)
        {
            char cyph[i]=(CharToAlphaNumber(plaintext[i])+key)%26; //Line 39
        }

        printf ("Cyphered:%s",cyph);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can add a comment at line 39 saying it's line 39.

Comment: `char cyph[i]=(CharToAlphaNumber(plaintext[i])+key)%26;` redeclares a new `cyph` inside the scope of your `for` loop that is independent of the one declared `char cyph[100];` outside the loop. Remove the `char` in front.

Comment: Please refrain from using numbers to represent characters.  Use a character literal, such as `'A'` or `'Z'`.  I haven't memorized the decimal codes in the ASCII table, your code is hard to read and understand.

Comment: You have a buffer overrun error when you use `scanf`.  Since you are only reading text, use `fgets` with `stdin`.  Also the `scanf` doesn't know about the 100 character limit of the array.

Comment: I recommend placing the value of `strlen(plaintext)` into a temporary variable and using it in the `for` loop.  This will prevent the code from executing the `strlen` function in each iteration (the `strlen` function searches each character in the string, it doesn't maintain a length property).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a variable scope issue:

```
    char cyph[100];  <--- cyph you intend to use
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<strlen(plaintext);i++)
    {
        char cyph[i]=(CharToAlphaNumber(plaintext[i])+key)%26;  <--- new cyph
    }
```

Inside your `for` loop, you've declared a new `cyph` via, `char cyph[i] = ...`. You've already declared `cyph` previously as `char cyphy[100];`, so you don't need to declare it again. Corrected:

```
    char cyph[100];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        cyph[i] = (CharToAlphaNumber(plaintext[i]) + key) % 26;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have second declaration of cyph table:

`char cyph[i]=(CharToAlphaNumber(plaintext[i])+key)%26;`

Moreover:

- `strlen(plaintext)` create variable that keeps length of string and use it in condition. Now program checks the length every loop round
- `int ascii=letter;` it is also not needed, you can use `letter` variable